# learning angular, having issues with ng-options

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I'm teaching myself angular and am stuck.

I have a simple html. page

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>shows tutorial</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="main.ctrl.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController as main">

<style>
.show_container {margin-bottom: 40px;}
.shows_list{padding: 20px 0;}
</style>

<div class="container">

    <h1>{{main.title}}</h1>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
            </span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="main.searchInput">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row show_container">
        <div class="col-lg-12"><h3>A list of TV shows</h3></div>
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="col-lg-6 shows_list" ng-repeat="show in main.shows | filter:main.searchInput">
                <h4>{{show.title}} </h4> 
                <span>{{show.year}}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <select class="form-control pull-right" ng-model="main.shows" ng-options="genre as show.genre for show in main.shows" ></select>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

my app.js file

```
angular.module('app', []);
```

and I have a controller set up with some data

```
angular.module('app')
.controller("MainController", function(){

    var vm = this;

    vm.title = 'AngularJS Tutorial Example';
    vm.searchInput = '';

    vm.shows = [
        {
            title: 'Game of Thrones',
            year: 2011,
            genre: 'Drama',
            favorite: true
        },
        {
            title: 'Walking Dead',
            year: 2010,
            genre: 'Suspense',
            favorite: true
        },
        {
            title: 'Firefly',
            year: 2002,
            genre: 'Drama',
            favorite: true
        },
        {
            title: 'Banshee',
            year: 2013,
            genre: 'Suspense',
            favorite: true
        },
        {
            title: 'Greys Anatomy',
            year: 2005,
            genre: 'Drama',
            favorite: false
        }
    ];
});
```

So Here's where I'm getting stuck.
1.) In my ng-options, the values disappear when I make a selection.
2.) I can not figure out how to group the "genres" 
3.) While the search input will refine the search, I would prefer to have the values return from the ng-options selection..

I am totally stuck and have been searching google for some help. While I have found tons of stiff using $scope, I want to try to stay with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values disappear when you make a selection because your `ng-model` must be assigned to other variable, not the whole shows array.

Here is a working plunker with your example:http://plnkr.co/edit/ypU7xqfoeHHspHLvDiz7?p=preview

I have created a searchInput, where `ng-model="main.searchInput.genre"` is used in your select tag.

Here is a function to create a genre list depending on your shows:

```
      vm.genres = [];

      vm.shows.forEach(function(element){
        if (vm.genres.indexOf(element.genre) == -1) {
          vm.genres.push(element.genre);
        }
      });
```

If you want to understand a little bit more of ng-options and select, here are 3 examples of different uses: http://plnkr.co/edit/Xc8Qrcr0AN4I2U0chbye?p=info

Comment: Okay so this worked spot on, i think i get it, but again, more questions.
1.) in the walkthru / tutorial that i started was trying, why was there a call to app.js that had only angular.module('app', []); when it seems like it can be handled in the main.ctrl.js ?
2.) where can I find a noobs guide to angular, with hand holding, as I am so beside myself. 

By the way worked perfect, I kind of understand it but am still just clueless.

Comment: Glad to help, you are learning, it is totally understandable.  https://egghead.io/technologies/angularjs has great tutorials, also the official documentation is of great help. Once you've earned a bit of practice I will recomend you to read todd motto's blog. It has a lot of awesome posts!

Comment: Okay two more questions, so 
1.)in the select list, is there a way to make a blank option, as it seems as if after selection, the empty value disappears,
2.) How would you make the list of shows be blank until an option is selected , and then if you go back to the emty value in the list, all the values hide..

I'm reading the docs, good stuff, but confusing, and I have no idea about the function provided ?? Sooooo lost in the angular weeds...

Comment: I have edited the plunker so that you can have what you want. 1) I have added to the genres array a blank element. 2) I have used the filter's comparator = true: {{ filter_expression | filter : expression : comparator}} This is essentially strict comparison of expected and actual. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Comment: I get it now.. Thank you so much. Unfortunatly my HS doesn't teach us angular, so trying to tech myself, learning by example helps. You are awesome. TY.

Answer (score 0):

ng-model should be the variable in which you store your selection:

```
    vm.selectedValue='';
```

in controller, and in the template:

```
    <select class="form-control pull-right" ng-model="main.selectedValue" ng-options="show.title group by show.genre for show in main.shows" ></select>
```